# philosophy's test

Tags: grammar, english-to-japanese

I want to say that I have a philosophy test today:
きょうは哲学のテストにする
is that OK?

Comment: Are you a teacher or a student?

Comment: The most common forms I can see in Japanese-English examples sentences for 'have a test' is 試験があります, though 試験 and テスト are acceptable variations. Another possibility is: テストを受ける. にする doesn't have quite the meaning your looking for. The dictionary says にする can be used to create a condition or assign a role; consider, feel, sense; set something in place; choose; and start or carry out. (Rough translation of Japanese dictionary). Dictionary is here https://www.google.com.au/search?q=%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B+%E6%84%8F%E5%91%B3&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=dV0mWa2xLomq0ATEs5TYCw

Answer (score 5):

You can write:

今日は哲学のテストがあります。

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are a student, I would use the very 受{う}ける or if it is formal 受験{じゅけん}

> きょうは哲学のテストを受ける。

Answer (score 3):

If you are a student of a school, 哲学の「テスト」が「ある」 is used commonly when the test will be done there, but 哲学の「試験」を「受ける」 is used to get something like a certification or an entrance permit.